# Solr Encoding/Decoding Data

Tags: java, encoding, solr, decode

I am trying to send a encoded string to Solr and then decode it on retrieval.  My encode looks like:

```
public static String compress(String inputString) {
    try {
        if (inputString == null || inputString.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return new String(compress(inputString.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


private static byte[] compress(byte[] input) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
        gzip.write(input);
        gzip.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then I send the to SOLR, and when I try to get it back (ignoring decoding for now because it fails here)

```
SolrDocument resultDoc = iter.next();
String content = (String) resultDoc.getFieldValue("source");
System.out.println(content);
```

If I send a string such as "Hello my name is Chris"  the encoded will look like (ignoring what stack overflow changed);

```
 ã�������ÛHÕ……W»≠T»KÃMU»,VpŒ( ,�ìùùG���
```

Yet what I get back from SOLR is

```
#31;ã#8;#0;#0;#0;#0;#0;#0;#0;ÛHÕ……W»≠T»KÃMU»,VpŒ( ,#6;#0;ìùùG#22;#0;#0;#0;
```

which will obviously make decoding fail.  I have tried using the Jetty install and Tomcat both with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this entry from the example schema.xml file that comes with the Solr distribution.

```
<!--Binary data type. The data should be sent/retrieved in as Base64 encoded Strings -->
<fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>
```

Make sure that the field you are using to store your encoded value in the index is using the `binary` fieldType and that you are using base64 encoded strings.